# Xamarin iOS List Content not writing to json files

Tags: xamarin.ios

We are using Visual Studio 2017, for developing iOS Application. We are facing issue in writing the data displayed in the list to the json file and we are using function streamwriter.

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Stream was not writable. occurred

Here I do want insert json file into ShopApp.Catalog_Master.json in portable project when clicking a saveButton:

```
private void saveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var employee = new Activity
    {
        Act_ID = 12345,
        Act_Name = "Peter",
        Act_Date = "13122017",
        Act_Rep = "Antony",
        Act_Type = "SalesOder"
    };

    // Throwing Unhandled Exception
    var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceText).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ShopApp.Catalog_Master.json");       

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(employee);
    }            
}
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? Put those details in the body of the question.

Comment: you can't write to files that are part of the app bundle.  The bundle is signed and is read only

Comment: We are working on shopping cart application for iOS xamarin. I have few product details in cart  listview, I want to write those details to json files. for that I am using streamwriter function and  that function is not writing details to json files , and it's not able to fetch file path of the json file , Here my project name is ShopApp and json file name is Catalog_Master.json. I have already pasted code above please help us

Comment: If you have any suggestion writing a listview details to json files, please let us know and share part of the code with us